# get request response from springboot handler method is not showing entity class object properly in postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, get

I am trying to fetch customer details from my database using spring boot handler method by incoming get request from postman. I am using birectional **@manytomany** relationship between **Account** and **Customer** entity classes.

Account class -

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int accountNumber;
    public String accountType;
    public int balance;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore 
    private List<Customer> customers;
}
//skipped constructors and getters setters
```

Customer class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int customerId;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customers")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Account> accounts;
}
```

Handler method in controller class -

```java
  // fetching all customers
    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public List<Customer> getallAccounts() {
        return (List<Customer>) this.customerServices.getAllAccounts();

    }
```

CustomerServices class -

```java
@Component
public class CustomerServices {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    // get all books
    public List<Customer> getAllAccounts() {
        System.out.println("Fetching all Customers");
        
        return (List<Customer>) this.customerRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And CustomerRepository interface -

```java
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {

}
```

When I am sending a get request to fetch all customers from the database
[image]

In response it is **not showing List of account class objects** that are mapped by ManyToMany relationship in Customer class.

I have no idea what is the error.
Somebody please help here.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically annotated `accounts` field with [`@JsonBackReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html) which means:

> Linkage is handled such that the property annotated with this annotation is **not serialized**;

If you don't serialize the `accounts` field of `Customer`, what JSON did you expect to get that would list `Account` objects when returning a list of `Customer` objects?

Returning a list of `Account` objects instead, and expecting sub-lists of `Customer` objects, will also not happen because of the [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) annotation, which pretty much have the same serialization effect as `@JsonBackReference`

There is no error here. The generated JSON is exactly what you asked the system to generate.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, I removed JsonBackReferrence from customer class then in response I am getting infinite json Could you tell the solution here? I am new to hibernate and spring boot both.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, But i don't want infinite json in my response. Is there any solution ?

Comment: Hi @Andreas,will JsonIdentityInfo solve my problem for bidrectional mapping as suggested by link -https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion